# How can I use .each for div if I use .append in AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I send AJAX and get HTML with many div element (.card), I use .append for add new .card elements after each AJAX request (like a infinity scroll). How can I use .each for all .card on page after one, two, three ...etc AJAX requests?

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$('.card').each(function(i) {
   addMarker(i);
}
});
```

and

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
$('.card').each(function(i) {
   addMarker(i);
}
});
```

not working.

I get count from zero on new .card divs every AJAX request.

Comment: @VasilyK, What are your trying to do? Do you want the number of elements in your page?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a container `<div class="container"></div>` where you are appending the cards `<div class="card"></div>` then you should use the following script:

```
$(document).scroll(function(){
    $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: "file.php",
        success: function(data){
            data = $.parseHTML(data);
            $.each( data, function( i, el ) {
                if (el.className == 'card') {
                    $(el).appendTo('.container');
                };
            });

            $('.card').each(function(i) {
                addMarker(i);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try my way, I think it will help you .

```
$(function(){
$.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: "data.action",
    success: function(data){
        $(data).find(".card").each(function(i, o){
                $(".container").append(o);
        });
        $('.card').each(function(i) {
            addMarker(i);
        });
    }
  });
});
```